# Getting "Configuration file is not well-formed XML" with � symbol

Tags: xml, iis

I'm setting up a new test server (IIS 7) and have copied over files from an existing test server only to get this error:

`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`

`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

with

`Configuration file is not well-formed XML`

Complaining of this line:

`<add key="DSN" value="server=.\;User ID=TestUser;Password=thisisnottherealpasswordbutithasa�init;Initial Catalog=TestDB" />`

which is actually this in the config file:

`<add key="DSN" value="server=.\;User ID=TestUser;Password=thisisnottherealpasswordbutithasa£init;Initial Catalog=TestDB" />`

If I remove the £ symbol from the password it loads properly, so I don't believe that this is simply masking another problem.

Also this same password is in configs for the other test servers and they load properly with it.

Am I possibly missing a set up stage for IIS that would affect which characters are allowed in an XML config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an encoding issue, the � sign is used in UTF-8 files to denote an invalid character. Like an iso-latin-1 encoded character that erroneously ended up in the UTF-8 file.

Comment: Yep. The culprit was me using Wordpad (my excuse was it was a new server..) to make a change further down. I ended up installing notepad++ just for quality of life, and saving the file with that fixed the encoding and the service. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use an entity for the £ symbol - I had a similar problem to this recently.  Either that or you can put it inside a CDATA section.